# Cut | Sort | Uniq -d -c | but?

Tags: shell

The given file is in the below format.

```
GGRPW,33332211,kr,P,SUCCESS,systemrenewal,REN,RAMS,SAA,0080527763,on:X,10.0,N,20120419,migr
GBRPW,1232221,uw,P,SUCCESS,systemrenewal,REN,RAMS,ASD,20075578623,on:X,1.0,N,20120419,migr
GLSH,21122111,uw,P,SUCCESS,systemrenewal,REN,RAMS,ASA,0264993503,on:X,10.0,N,20120419,migr
```

I need to take out duplicates and count(each duplicates categorized by f1,2,5,14). Then insert into database with the first duplicate occurence record entire fields and tag the count(dups) in another column. For this I need to cut all the 4 mentioned fields and sort and find the dups using uniq -d and for counts I used -c. Now again coming back after all sorting out of dups and it counts I need the output to be in the below form.

```
3,GLSH,21122111,uw,P,SUCCESS,systemrenewal,REN,RAMS,ASA,0264993503,on:X,10.0,N,20120419,migr
```

Whereas three being the number of repeated dups for f1,2,5,14 and rest of the fields can be from any of the dup rows.

By this way dups should be removed from the original file and show in the above format.
And the remaining in the original file will be uniq ones they go as it is...

---

What I have done is..

```
awk '{printf("%5d,%s\n", NR,$0)}' renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt > n_renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt 
cut -d',' -f2,3,6,15 n_renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt |sort | uniq -d -c
```

but this needs a point back again to the original file to get the lines for the dup occurences. ..

let me not confuse.. this needs a different point of view.. and my brain is clinging on my approach.. need a cigar.. 
Any thots...??

Comment: have a cigar :) do the whole thing in awk.

Comment: agree. at least, cut is not needed.

Answer (score 4):

sort has an option  **-k**

> ```
>    -k, --key=POS1[,POS2]
>           start a key at POS1, end it at POS2 (origin 1)
> ```

uniq has an option  **-f**

> ```
>    -f, --skip-fields=N
>           avoid comparing the first N fields
> ```

so sort and uniq with field numbers(count NUM and test this cmd yourself, plz)

```
awk -F"," '{print $0,$1,$2,...}' file.txt | sort -k NUM,NUM2 | uniq -f NUM3 -c
```

Comment: If the purpose of the `awk` is to transform commas to spaces, `tr` would be a better choice\

Answer (score 0):

Using awk's associative arrays is a handy way to find unique/duplicate rows:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
    {
        key = $1 FS $2 FS $5 FS $14
        if (key in count) 
            count[key]++
        else {
            count[key] = 1
            line[key] = $0
        }
    }
    END {for (key in count) print count[key], line[key]}
' filename
```

Comment: Sorry just saw the pop-ups for SO replies for my query.

Comment: I found it using subsep and ofcourse I got this from one of the linux forums..                                                              awk -F, '!(($1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $14) in uniq){uniq[$1,$2,$5,$14]=$0}{count[$1,$2,$5,$14]++}END{for(i in count){if(count[i] > 1)file= "'"$DVAR"'";else file="'"$UVAR"'";print uniq[i],","count[i] > file}}' renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt

Answer (score 0):

SYNTAX :

awk -F, '!(($1 SUBSEP $2 SUBSEP $5 SUBSEP $14) in uniq){uniq[$1,$2,$5,$14]=$0}{count[$1,$2,$5,$14]++}END{for(i in count){if(count[i] > 1)file="dupes";else file="uniq";print uniq[i],","count[i] > file}}' renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt

Calculation:

sym@localhost:~$ cut -f16 -d',' uniq | sort | uniq -d -c
124275 1 -----> SUM OF UNIQ ( 1 )ENTRIES

sym@localhost:~$ cut -f16 -d',' dupes | sort | uniq -d -c
3860 2
850 3
71 4
7 5
3 6
sym@localhost:~$ cut -f16 -d',' dupes | sort | uniq -u -c

### 1 7

10614 ------> SUM OF DUPLICATE ENTRIES MULTIPLIED WITH ITS COUNTS

sym@localhost:~$ wc -l renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt
134889 renewstatus_2012-04-19.txt ---> TOTAL LINE COUNTS OF THE ORIGINAL FILE, MATCHED EXACTLY WITH (124275+10614) = 134889